# WebServer: Postgresql + Iptables -> Allow from localhost

Tags: linux, php, iptables, web-server, postgresql

I have a web server with: Debian 9 + Postgres 9.6 + Apache 2.4.25

I've created a bash script with the configuration of the iptables:

```
!/bin/bash

# IP Server
IP="192.168.0.18"

# Restart default config
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z

# Enable different protections to kernel
#
# Ignore broadcast icmp
echo -n '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
# Disable Source Routing
echo -n '0' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route
# Disable ICMP redirects
echo -n '0' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects
# Protection to "bad error messages"
echo -n '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses
# Disable ip forwarding
echo -n '0' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# Login "source routed" and redirects
echo -n '1' >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians

# Default, deny INPUT y FORWARD
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow outgoing traffic
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Deny new TCP connections not started with SYN
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "TCP RST,ACK,FIN"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Deny fragments
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -f -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fragment Packets"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -f -j DROP

# Deny souspicius packages
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

# Deny NULL packets
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "NULL Packets"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Deny packages "Christmas tree"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "XMAS Packets"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP

# Deny attacks Fin Scan
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fin Packets Scan"
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP

# Validate flags TCP
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP

# Deny invalids packages
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Allow all lo interface
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -p all -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow port 22 (SSH)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $IP --sport 1024:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow port 443 (HTTPS)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $IP --sport 1024:65535 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow 80 (HTTP)
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $IP --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow POSTGRES remote console from IP

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s 192.168.0.4/32 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 

# Allow connections POSTGRES from localhost

#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $IP --sport 1024:65535 --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Log and deny
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

# Deny all outgoing traffic except established connections

iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing traffic HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -s $IP -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing traffic 80
iptables -A OUTPUT -s $IP -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing traffic ping
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s $IP -d 0/0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing traffic DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -s $IP -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s $IP -p udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

From my web site, hosted in this server, I cann't login :(

The error message of the webserver log is:

```
[Tue Mar 27 12:53:30.690759 2018] [:error] [pid 1853] [client 192.168.0.4:58098] PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out\n\tIs the server running on host &quot;localhost&quot; (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address\n\tIs the server running on host &quot;localhost&quot; (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The problem sure are iptables config because I disable iptables the login is working fine.

Please Could you help me?

Comment: Your setup seems to be quite verbose with logging, could you paste any log messages generated by iptables when you attempt to connect to Postgres? Also you may be interested in utilising UNIX sockets for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

On the output chain, you are allowing the server to inititate connections to HTTP, HTTPS, ICMP, DNS - but not to the postgres port (tcp/5432) - or to localhost for that matter.

`iptables -A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`